# Question Answer model for Polish language

Tags: python, machine-learning, nlp-question-answering

I am wondering is there any polish language or Slavic language model on the base of which I could build a new model with my training set?

Comment: This might be helpful https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/39656/stemmer-lemmatizer-for-polish-language?rq=1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There're a lot of pretrained embedders, like [LASER](https://engineering.fb.com/ai-research/laser-multilingual-sentence-embeddings/) from Facebook. There's unofficial [pypi](https://github.com/yannvgn/laserembeddings) lib, but it works just fine. If you want to reach seminal-like scores, there's no point in doing this all by hand. Embedders usually covers dozens of languages, so you can feed training data in any language you want. Your models will also work for those language out-of-the-box, even if you trained them on other languages.